# Асинхронный запрос к API. JSON отдача

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Здравствуйте!

Возник такой вопрос: Для связи с сервером использую `HttpClient`, а затем разбор полученного `JSON` объекта средствами класса `JSONObject`. Все операции проходят в асинхронном режиме `AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>`.

При падении интернета, может возникнуть ситуация, что асинхронный запрос не выполнит свою функцию. И внутри него произойдет ошибка, которая приведет к падению приложения.

Есть ли какой либо `Framework` для `Android` выполняющий подобную задачу (предполагаю, что в нем уже будут реализованы необходимые проверки)?

Comment: эм, такого ну должно произойти :) 
Везде, где может быть падение, при запросах, пробрасывает IOException, и вы ее либол обрабатываете, либо пробрасываете дальше, но без обработки у вас даже не скомпилится

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая штука как retrofit. Где результат выполнения может быть возвращён как rxObservable или Callback. А там вы уже сами можете реализовать логику обработки ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

К `api google` велит по другому обращаться

- **Activity → Service → ContentProvider**, `Activity` взаимодействует с сервисом для выполнения сетевых запросов, сервис сохраняет полученные из сети данные в ContentProvider, откуда потом Activity их получает
- **Activity → ContentProvider → Service**, `Activity` взаимодействует только с ContentProvider, ContentProvider выполняет сетевые запросы через сервис;
- **Activity → ContentProvider → SyncAdapter**, аналогично предыдущему, но предназначено для специфической ситуации, в которой локальные данные полностью синхронизируются с данными в облаке. В качестве примера можно
  указать на контакты в аккаунте `Google`;
  [первый патерн статья на хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176729/)

Virgil Dobjanschi врать не будет )))

Comment: Спасибо! Тем не менее решительно выступаю против ContentProvider. Цитирую: "Для работы внутри одного приложения такой подход решительно не годится, так как порой исключение поднимается с самого нижнего уровня данных вплоть до пользовательского интерфейса. Например, сообщение о недоступности веб-сервиса или об ошибке авторизации." А в дополнение неразумность их использования оправергнута здесь - http://habrahabr.ru/post/134305/

Comment: Читал эту статью, как это часто бывает комментарии освещают проблему глубже чем статья, "одно приложение" это так раз то что ставится под сомнение если работу с сетью выполняет Service, тоесть его можно рассматривать как другое приложение. Пользователь может закрыть приложение не дождавшись завершения сетевой операции, пользователь может вообще не запустить приложение.  
Тоже приведу цитату"Запрос и парсинг ответа от веб-сервиса должен делаться на стороне Service (в термина Андроид). И если произошла какая-либо ошибка, то уже сервис сделает callback на активити, которая запросила данные."

Comment: тут я с вами не согласен, все зависит от того, как будет использоваться информация полученная с сервера